# An integral of the function $f(x^2)$ when $x^2$ is set equal to $t$

Tags: calculus, integration

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukqck.png)

Given that $F^{\prime}(x)=f(x)$,find the value of the integral below:
$$
\int_{a}^{b} x f\left(x^{2}\right) d x
$$

**Work**: (wondering if the work and the answer is correct. Thank you very much):
[Original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEHzK.jpg)

Given:
$$
F^{\prime}(x)=f(x)
$$
Let $$I=\int_{a}^{b} x \cdot f\left(x^{2}\right) d x\tag1\label{eq1}$$
Let $$x^{2}=t \quad \Rightarrow \quad x d x=\frac{d t}{2}$$

So from Equation $\ref{eq1}$

$$I=\frac{1}{2} \int_{a}^{b} f(t) d t$$
$$I=\frac{1}{2}[F(t)]_{a}^{b}$$
$$I=L_{2}^{L}\left[F\left(x^{2}\right)\right]_{a}^{b}$$
$$\Rightarrow \quad I=\frac{1}{2}\left(F\left(b^{2}\right)-F\left(a^{2}\right)\right)$$
So
$$I=\frac{F\left(b^{2}\right)-F\left(a^{2}\right)}{2}$$

Comment: We prefer [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to unsearchable images. For example, my answer's calculation is `$$t=x^2\implies xdx=\tfrac12dt\implies\int_a^bxf(x)dx=\int_{a^2}^{b^2}\tfrac12f(t)dt=\tfrac12(F(b^2)-F(a^2)).$$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's right. It can be made more concise viz.$$t=x^2\implies xdx=\tfrac12dt\implies\int_a^bxf(x)dx=\int_{a^2}^{b^2}\tfrac12f(t)dt=\tfrac12(F(b^2)-F(a^2)).$$